# NavigationRail with go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-go-router

I'm developing a web/desktop application that has a fairly standard UI layout involving a `NavigationRail` on the left and a content pane taking up the remainder of the screen.

[image]

I've reciently added `go_router` so I can properly support URLs in web browsers, however in doing so I have lost the ability to have any form of transition/animation when moving between pages as calling `context.go()` causes a hard cut to the next page.

Theres also the issue that `go_router` routes have to return the full page to be rendered meaning I need to include the navigation rail on every page rather than each page being just the content relevant to that page. I believe this is also the main reason all animations are broken, because clicking a link effectively destroys the current navigation rail and builds a new one for the new page

I couldn't see anything in `go_router` but is there any form of builder API available that can output and refresh a single section of the page? I'm thinking of something like `bloc`'s `BlocBuilder` which listens for state changes and rebuilds just the widget its responsible for when a change occures.

Alternatively, is there a way to update the current URL without rebuilding the whole page?

Or is `go_router` just not capable of what I'm after, and if so, are there any alternatives that can do this?

The overall effecti I'm after is similar to the material site https://m3.material.io/develop
Clicking around the various buttons feels like you are navigating around within an app rather than clicking on links and loading new pages

Thanks for your help

Comment: See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99095

Comment: I'm thinking the right thing to do would be putting the navigation rail _above_ the `Navigator` via `MaterialApp.router(builder:`. However, this causes an `No GoRouter found in context` error, as discussed [here](https://github.com/csells/go_router/discussions/212), for which I do not yet have a workaround.

Comment: Looks like you can work around the `No GoRouter found in context` by using `routerConfig.routerDelegate.navigatorKey.currentContext` as your `.go(context)` `context`. I was able to get things working this way. Hopefully I'll be able to summarize an answer in a few days. If I don't, an implementation should soon be available in my [Dansdata Portal repository](https://github.com/dansdata-se/portal)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a Shell Route. I got the idea when going through the [go_router 5 migration guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10l22o4ml4Ss83UyzqUC8_xYOv_QjZEi80lJDNE4q7wM/edit?pli=1&resourcekey=0-U-BXBQzNfkk4v241Ow-vZg#). I saw that they had a `navigatorBuilder` property in which they were wrapping every route in a Scaffold with AppBar. And it said to migrate:

Before migration:

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
 routes: <GoRoute> [
   GoRoute(
     path: '/',
     builder: (_, __) => const Text('/'),
   ),
   GoRoute(
     path: '/a',
     builder: (_, __) => const Text('/a'),
   )
 ],
 navigatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(title: Text(state.location)),
     body: child,
   );
 }
);
```

After Migration:

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
 routes: <GoRoute> [
   ShellRoute(
     builder: (_, GoRouterState state, child) {
       return Scaffold(
         body: child, 
         appBar: AppBar(title: Text(state.location)),
       );
     },
     routes: [
       GoRoute(
         path: 'a',
         builder: (_, __) => const Text('a'),
       ),
       GoRoute(
         path: 'b',
         builder: (_, __) => const Text('b'),
       )
     ],
   ),
 ],
);
```

Now every route in the `ShellRoute.routes` property will be wrapped with that `Scaffold` and `AppBar`, it will not rebuild upon navigation, so will behave as a persistent `AppBar`, `NavigationBar`, or whatever should. Now it shows the page transition animations when you do `context.go('some_route')` (for example from a `NavigationBar` in the `ShellRoute`). You also don't run into the issue Felix ZY was having, accessing `GoRouter` from the `context`.

A `NavigationRail` would just be like this in the shell route:

```
ShellRoute(
 builder: (_, GoRouterState state, child) {
   return Scaffold(
  body: Column(children:[Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      NavigationRail(....)]),
  child,]));
});
```

}

Comment: In my case I show a BottomNavigationBar or a NavigationRail based on the display's orientation. The BottomNavigationBar works fine (doesn't re-render) but the NavigationRail has the issue.
In your answer, you show an AppBar working fine, but that's not the issue in question.

Comment: @FilippoOrrù  I have added what the code would be for `NavigationRail` in the solution. You can add conditional rendering in there too. The rebuilding is not affected by having a `NavigationRail`. Rebuilding is controlled by your widget state. I have wrapped my Scaffold with `ResponsiveBuilder` a third party package to rebuild on different screen sizes which causes my shell route to rebuild and conditionally render with a `Scaffold.appBar` or `Scaffold.bottomNavigationBar`